# TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined nodejs express mvc

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to render "result" in my "home-page" view using this function in my controller, which is calling my model to make the query.

```
exports.searchNoms = (req, res) => {
    getDatabaseModel.searchNoms(req).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        res.render('Home/home-page', {
            nomenclature: result
        });
    }).catch((err) => setImmediate(() => {
        throw err;
    }))
};
```

I'm getting my result which displays a string as I wanted.

But then I'm getting the following error :
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined at C:\somepath\controllers\nomenclature.controller.js:36:14`

I've tried a few things and if I change my route calling this function in my controller from :

```
`router.post('/search-noms', function (req, res) {nomenclatureController.searchNoms(req.body.idNoms)})`
```

To :

```
`router.post('/search-noms', nomenclatureController.searchNoms)`
```

It works. But I need that body parameter in order to achieve what I want to do.

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mark1: Just get idNoms from your req.body, and put it into `getDatabaseModel.searchNoms(idNoms)`, that's all.

```js
exports.searchNoms = (req, res) => {
    // mark1
    const idNoms = req.body.idNoms

    getDatabaseModel.searchNoms(idNoms).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        res.render('Home/home-page', {
            nomenclature: result
        });
    }).catch((err) => setImmediate(() => {
        throw err;
    }))
};
```

Then in your router

```js
router.post('/search-noms', nomenclatureController.searchNoms)
```

Comment: Can't believe I got stuck on that ;_;

Thank you very much !